# Issue getting checkbox values class and added them up if the checkbox is checked using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have 20 or so HTML inputs of type checkbox with `add` class. I am trying to use a plain JavaScript function to find the ones that are checked and get the value from those, then add them up and display the total back. Sadly I cannot seem to pull the values correctly.

I have been trying to get the checkbox values with `document.getElementsByClassName` and then looping through to pull out the values if the boxes were checked

```
function figure() {
    var totalCost = 0;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('add');
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i].checked) {
            totalCost = totalCost + parseFloat(x[i].value);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("TOTAL").innerHTML = "$" + totalCost;
}
```

I am expecting the total of the checked boxes to be displayed but I get nothing and the following error in **Chrome**.

> packageCal.html:151 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined at figure (packageCal.html:151) at HTMLInputElement.onclick (packageCal.html:142)" Line 151 is "if (x[i].checked) {

Comment: `for (i = 0; x.length; i++) {` The second part of a `for` should be the condition, eg `i < x.length` (also, you may use `querySelectorAll` and `:checked` instead to avoid having to iterate manually)

Comment: For example `function figure() {
  var totalCost = 0, x = document.querySelectorAll('.add:checked');
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    totalCost += parseFloat(x[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById("TOTAL").innerHTML = "$" + totalCost.toFixed(2);
}`

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: Also make sure there are at least one checkbox with `class=add` and no OTHER elements with `class="add"` that are not checkboxes. In your case you loop too far because x.length is always `truthy` if not 0

Answer (score 0):

In for loop the condition for loop continuation is not correct. I have pasted the corrected code below.

```
function figure() {
var totalCost = 0;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('add');
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i<=x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].checked) {
        totalCost = totalCost + parseFloat(x[i].value);
    }
}
document.getElementById("TOTAL").innerHTML = "$" + totalCost;
```

}

and if the error is still there check all the elements which were assigned the class name you are searching for.